# Unable to mount USB CD Drive

Tags: centos, mount, usb-device, data-cd

I have a Linux machine running CentOS7 that does not have a built-in CD drive. I need to copy files from a CD onto the computer, so I'm using a USB CD drive. I cannot get the computer to recognize the device and mount the CD.

The device doesn't show up in `/dev`, but I've been able to identify the device using `sudo lshw -short`, with the following output:

`/0/100/14/0/8/1         storage   Dell DVD+/-RW Drive DW316`

Without the `-short`, the only other interesting info I see is that the device is always listed as `-usb UNCLAIMED`, regardless of which USB port I use.

I tried mounting the device using the command `sudo mount /0/100/14/0/8/1 /mnt` but returned the error "Special device does not exist".

I also looked at the info from `lsblk` and `fdisk -l`, but there were no changes when plugging or unplugging the CD reader.

What else should I do to mount this CD? I was able to use the CD reader on a Windows machine, so I know the device is working.

Comment: Are you sure the drive is OK? Is the cable broken? Does the drive get enough power (some need *two* USB connections, one for data and one for power)?

Comment: @vonbrand I'm pretty sure it's working, especially since I was able to read the CD on another machine. There's only one cable, and when I plug it in to the CentOS machine the disk spins for a bit and then stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon the solution in another forum - our security settings had USB devices disabled. I uncommented the following line in `/etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage.conf`

```
install usb-storage /bin/true
```

After editing the file, I rebooted and the CD mounted itself automatically. After copying all of the data over I uncommented the above line and rebooted again to reset back to normal operation.

*Side note: I also read that an authorized user should be able to use `insmod` to enable USB devices temporarily without modifying the /etc file. Anyone know how one would do this?*